# Click bt, there is no response, the button has been clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```java
public void Init(){
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JButton bt=new JButton("按钮");
    JCheckBox checkBox1=new JCheckBox("aaaaa");
    JCheckBox checkBox2=new JCheckBox("bbbbb");
    JCheckBox checkBox3=new JCheckBox("ccccc");

    JCheckBox checkBox4=new JCheckBox("ddddd");
    JCheckBox checkBox5=new JCheckBox("eeeee");

    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(checkBox4);
            panel.add(checkBox5);
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });

    panel.add(bt);
    panel.add(checkBox1);
    panel.add(checkBox2);
    panel.add(checkBox3);

    frame.add(panel);
}
```

When I click `bt` there is no response, the button has been clicked.

I hope to be able to perform the operations in `actionPerformed` after clicking `bt`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your code does not work as expected is because you are missing two important steps after removing all the components from the panel. You need to call `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()` to update the panel's layout and appearance. Otherwise, the changes will not be reflected on the screen. You can fix your code:

```
public void Init(){
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JButton bt=new JButton("按钮");
    JCheckBox checkBox1=new JCheckBox("aaaaa");
    JCheckBox checkBox2=new JCheckBox("bbbbb");
    JCheckBox checkBox3=new JCheckBox("ccccc");

    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.removeAll(); // remove all components from the panel
            panel.revalidate(); // update the panel's layout
            panel.repaint(); // repaint the panel
        }
    });

    panel.add(bt);
    panel.add(checkBox1);
    panel.add(checkBox2);
    panel.add(checkBox3);

    frame.add(panel);
}
```

Comment: The code has been modified.